# how can i hide cuurent element on pure javascrtipt with this code onclick

Tags: javascript, events, dom, click

i need to hide CURRENT element by clicking:

```
var triggerEl = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for (var i=0;i<triggerEl.length;i++){
    triggerEl[this].addEventListener("click", hide);
}
function hide(i){
    var e = document.querySelectorAll( 'p+.box');
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
        e[this].style.display = (e[this].style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('p').addEventListener('click', event =>
  event.target.style.display = event.target.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'
)
```